# Multiple formatter functions in Bokeh datatable

Tags: datatable, bokeh, formatter

Is it possible to do multiple format types within one "formatter"? For example:

```
TableColumn(field="y", title="y",formatter=HTMLTemplateFormatter(), NumberFormatter(),DateFormatter())
```

etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. Bokeh currently only accepts a single CellFormatter per TableColumn. You could try opening an issue on [Bokeh's Github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh) to allow thge formatter argument to accept a list of CellFormatters. Or, you may look into hooking up either a JS or python callback to the TableColumn to do some more sophisticated formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Two and a half years later, but...... This is currently being developed now. Keep an eye on the Bokeh repo for addition of this function, hopefully in the near future.

Comment: This should possibly be a comment until it is actually released.